# Ocatave Symbolic "Python cannot import SymPy"

Tags: python, macos, octave, sympy

After installing octave, sympy (through anaconda), and the symbolic package, I'm trying to run this line in octave as part of a script:

```
syms nn nb x
```

When I do I get this message:

```
warning: the 'syms' function belongs to the symbolic package from Octave Forge
which you have installed but not loaded.  To load the package, run `pkg
load symbolic' from the Octave prompt.
```

After:

```
pkg load symbolic
syms nn nb x
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sympy/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImportError("It appears 2to3 has been run on the codebase. Use "
 ImportError: It appears 2to3 has been run on the codebase. Use Python 3 or get the original source code.
OctSymPy v2.4.0: this is free software without warranty, see source.
Initializing communication with SymPy using a popen2() pipe.
error: Python cannot import SymPy: have you installed SymPy?
error: called from
     assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 37 column 5
     python_ipc_popen2 at line 78 column 5
     python_ipc_driver at line 57 column 13
     python_cmd at line 166 column 9
     sym at line 365 column 5
     syms at line 162 column 9
```

I'm using OSX El Capitan and I installed Octave through homebrew.

If I'm being honest, I have no clue what is going on here... Is it that octave is unable to properly communicate with sympy? If so I'm guessing there might be a simple way to fix this? If this isn't it what should I do? I'm open to restarting the process.

I'd like to apologize for any formatting issues ahead of time, this is my first time asking. I didn't see any questions covering this but if I missed something obvious, I'm sorry again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an old version of SymPy. Try upgrading to the newest version (1.0 at the time of writing).

Comment: I have the latest SymPy (1.0) installed in OS X 10.11.6 through Anaconda and I'm seeing the same error. During `pkg install symbolic-2.4.0.tar.gz` I get a warning that SymPy cannot be located. `pkg load symbolic` works, but `syms x` produces the error.

Comment: @apraetor you probably need to configure the symbolic package to find the Anaconda Python. I would open a new question about it.

Comment: I wound up removing the packages and installing Octave-Symbolic through MacPorts instead (worked perfectly). Anaconda Python is the default Python interpreter on my system though. I had assumed that would be enough. Thanks for the response.